# VBA: Filtrar múltiplos itens de uma Tabela Dinâmica contendo determinado texto

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, filtro

Estou tentando rodar um código que filtre todos os itens de uma Tabela Dinâmica que contenham um determinado texto. Imaginei que apenas usando asteríscos (*) antes e depois de mina palavra-chave eu conseguiria obter resultado, mas o VBA lê os asteríscos como caracteres literais.
Como faço para filtrar TODOS os itens que tenham a palavra escrita na InputBox?

```
Sub FilterCustomers()

    Dim f As String: f = InputBox("Type the text you want to filter:")

    With Sheets("Customers").PivotTables("Customers_PivotTable")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFields("Concatenation for filtering").CurrentPage = "*f*"
        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para filtrar múltiplos items numa Tabela Dinâmica, vc deve ler item a item e marcá-los como visíveis ou não. E, para comparar textos contidos em outros, deve-se usar a declaração `Like`. Assim, a forma mais adequada de escrever o código com a finalidade desejada é:

```
Sub FilterCstomers()

    Dim f As String: f = InputBox("Type the text you want to filter:")

    Dim PvtItm As PivotItem
    With Sheets("Customers Pivot").PivotTables("Customers_PivotTable")
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each PvtItm In .PivotFields("Concatenation for filtering").PivotItems
            If PvtItm.Name Like "*" & f & "*" Then
                PvtItm.Visible = True
            Else
                PvtItm.Visible = False
                End If
            Next PvtItm
        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Obrigado @Julio_L_Muller, ajudou muito!

Consegui inclusive filtrar 2 palavras diferentes simultaneamente (exemplo1 e exemplo2), segue:

```
Sub FilterCstomers()

    Dim f As String: f = InputBox("Type the text you want to filter:")

    Dim PvtItm As PivotItem
    With Sheets("Customers Pivot").PivotTables("Customers_PivotTable")
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each PvtItm In .PivotFields("Concatenation for filtering").PivotItems
            If PvtItm.Name Like "exemplo1" Then
                PvtItm.Visible = True
            Else
                If PvtItm.Name Like "exemplo2" then
                else
                PvtItm.Visible = False
                End If
            End If
        Next PvtItm
    End With

End Sub
```